# Natural Tranformation in a More General Context

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

I've been building my way up through some category theory in Haskell on my way to creating more general Monads.

Before I can move onto the next step I am going to need to be able to work with natural transformations.

Now natural transformations on regular `Functor`s are easy enough they are just functions

```
trans :: forall a . F a -> G a
```

(where `F` and `G` are `Functor`s) with the additional restriction that

```
fmap f . trans = trans . fmap f
```

equivalent to the commutative diagram:

[image: commutative diagram]

However when I move on to more categorical functors

```
class
  ( Category cat1
  , Category cat2
  )
    => Functor cat1 cat2 f
  where
    map :: cat1 a b -> cat2 (f a) (f b)
```

I am not sure how I can augment the definition of natural transformation to keep up.

The diagram implies that

```
trans :: forall a . cat2 (F a) (G a)
```

where

```
Functor cat1  cat2 F
Functor cat1' cat2 G
```

However it is not clear to me that it must be the case that `cat1 ~ cat1'`.  Or what the relationship between the transformation and the precategories of both functors are.

What does a natural tranformation look like in the broader context of Haskell `Functor`s over more general categories?

Comment: The functors F and G must be parallel in the definition of natural transformation. One can also define a category [cat1, cat2] having functors cat1->cat2 as *objects* and natural transformations as morphisms. Note how, in this category, all functors are parallel (going from the same cat1 to the same other cat2)

Answer (score 4):

> However it is not clear to me that it must be the case that cat1 ~ cat1'.

It's part of the definition of a natural transformation that the functors F and G have the same domain and codomain. [From nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+transformation):

> Given categories C and D, and functors F, G : C -> D

So a direct translation of the definition in Haskell is that a natural transformation between functors `F, G` with domain `cat1` and codomain `cat2` is as a polymorphic term, a family of morphisms `cat2 (F a) (G a)` indexed by objects `a`:

```hs
n :: forall a. cat2 (F a) (G a)
```

such that a certain diagram commutes for all `f :: cat1 a b`, i.e., we have the following equation, where `(.)` is composition in `cat2`:

```hs
fmap f . n = n . fmap f
```

where `n` is specialized at type `a` on the left, and at type `b` on the right.

Note that this encoding is limited in expressiveness, because Haskell `forall` is not identical to English "for all". The behavior of `n :: forall a. ...` cannot really depend on `a`. `forall` implies a form of "uniformity" (aka. parametricity) which is not found in the definition of "natural transformations".